# When i click on child menu parent menu should highlight

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

when we click on sub menu parent menu should highlight. Please check my Javascript code. I am unable to get the result.Here i got the results only main menu highlighted.  Please help me.Thanks in advance

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cssmenu a').each(function(index) {
            if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            {
            //check if 1st level, then below condition
            //if(this.class() != "has-parent")
            //{
               // $(this).addClass("active");
            //} 
                //if not first level, assign active to parent of this
            //if(this.class()= "has-parent")
            //{
                $(this).addClass("active");
            //}     
                }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
     .active{
      background: #4FA9E4; color:#FFF;

    }

    <ul id="id">
    <body>
    <div id="cssmenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="company.php">Company</a>

            <ul><li class="has-parent"><a href="a.php">a</a></li>
            <li><a href="b.php">b</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li  class="has-sub"><a href="patners.php">Patners</a>
            <ul><li><a href="c.php">c</a></li>
            <li><a href="d.php">d</a></li></ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you paste your code into [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) It might be easier for us to debug your code that way.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the style tag which is what caused the problem. Also I added some other tags you forgot like doctype and head tags. Validate your document http://validator.w3.org/ and you won't get problems like these anymore.

```
<!doctype html><html><head><title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cssmenu a').each(function(index) {console.log(this.href);
            if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            {
            //check if 1st level, then below condition
            //if(this.class() != "has-parent")
            //{
               // $(this).addClass("active");
            //} 
                //if not first level, assign active to parent of this
            //if(this.class()= "has-parent")
            //{
                $(this).addClass("active");
            //}     
                }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
     .active{
      background: #4FA9E4; color:#FFF;display:block;

    }
    </style>
</head><body>

    <div id="cssmenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="company.php">Company</a>

            <ul><li class="has-parent"><a href="a.php">a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#asd">b</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li  class="has-sub"><a href="patners.php">Patners</a>
            <ul><li><a href="c.php">c</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php">d</a></li></ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Company</a>

        <ul><li class="has-parent"><a href="#">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li  class="has-sub"><a href="#">Patners</a>
        <ul><li><a href="#">c</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">d</a></li></ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#cssmenu li').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('has-parent')){
            var parent = $(this).closest('.has-sub');
            parent.attr('class', 'active');
        }
    });
});
```

Styles:

```
    .active{
      background: #4FA9E4; color:#FFF;
}
```

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Q25T/1/).

Comment: I am not getting the exact answer what i want please any one help me by giving correct code, the code which i gave in first is only highlighting what am clicking,but i want when i click submenu main menu should highlight,please help

Answer (score 0):

add click function

```
 $('#cssmenu a').unbind('click').click(function(){
            $(this).addClass("active");
            return false;
    });
```

Sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/89tav/2/)